# Unwanted gaps in embedded divs at certain resolutions [chrome]

Tags: html, css

I have a React component that is trying to simulate a progress bar. For simplicity sake, I've paired it down to the code-snippet below:

```css
.bar {
  background-color: #EAECEF;
  border: 1px solid #3D4D5B;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #3D4D5B;
  color: #000;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that at certain resolutions, unwanted gaps start to appear between the inner div and the outer div. This can be shown by simply zooming in (ctrl-+) the rendered progress bar. I've only noticed this behavior with Chromium-based browsers and not with Firefox.

Does anyone know why this would be happening and/or have any suggestions on how to address this issue?

Comment: This is normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to remove `border` style from `bar` div element?
It will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening because of the border (1px) which appears/disappears when zooming in/out. Now, the issue is solved only by removing the border.

```css
.bar {
  background-color: #EAECEF;
  /*border: 1px solid #3D4D5B;*/
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #3D4D5B;
  color: #000;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```